# systemd user units and debian wheezy

Tags: debian, daemon, systemd

I'm running a debian wheezy server and switched to systemd by installing `systemd-sysv`. So far everything works as before. Now I want to allow users to run/ manage their own units/ daemons with systemd. For a simple test I tried running `systemctl --user` as a normal user, but it always fails with:

```
gucki@debian:~$ systemctl --user
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

How can I fix this? I do not want to run/ install any graphical stuff on the server, I don't need X11.

UPDATE 1: 
I finally managed to find out the error is output because there's no systemd user manager for user gucki running. When I start it as root using `systemctl start user@gucki.service` everything works as expected.

HOWEVER: 
I was not yet able to get the service `user@gucki.service` automatically started on boot. When I symlink `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/user@gucki.service -> /lib/systemd/system/user@.service` the service is started, however the user gucki get's the same error message as before. Doing a "systemctl restart user@gucki.service" as root hangs until I hit ctrl-c. According to ps it's hanging in "/bin/systemd-tty-ask-password-agent --watch".

So finally I "only" wonder how I can get user@gucki.service  started automatically on boot?

UPDATE 2:
It seems the version of systemd in wheezy is *very* old (44) and buggy. I upgraded to 204 from backports (still old, current is 217) but it seems to work now as expected.